# Sum Checkboxes without POSTING values - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I've had a look around but could find a definitve answer.

Basically, I have a Total, with an ID that im trying to automatically update once a checkbox is clicked.

```
p style="font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold;"><b>Total Cost:</b> £<input value="0.00" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="total"/></p>
```

The checkbox will have a simple value such as 1.50 or similar. (these are dynamic) so

```
<input name="product" value="<?php echo $count*0.50 ?>" type="checkbox">
```

This may be very simple! But im not that hands on with Javascript

Comment: you can listen for a change event on your checkboxes, then get the value of each checkbox, add them, and then update the result of your p tag with id total.

Comment: Can you create an example with jsbin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling both checking and unchecking a box to update the sum for the input with a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yolivuremi/edit?html,js,output) example, also assuming you are using jquery.

```
var sum = 0;
var total = $('#total');
var cbox = $('.cbox');

$('.cbox').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
    updateTotal();
  } else {
    sum -= parseFloat($(this).val());
    updateTotal();
  }
});

function updateTotal() {
  total.val(sum);
}
```

Comment: Having global variables would not be ideal

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
   var sum = 0;
   $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
       sum += Number($(this).val());
   });

   $('#total').val(sum);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you just want the checked "product" check boxes:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="product"]').on('change', function() {
  var newtotal = 0;
  $('input[type="checkbox"][name="product"]').filter(":checked").each(function() {
    newtotal = newtotal + Number($(this).val());
  });
  $('#total').val(newtotal);
});
```

Sample fiddle to play around with: https://jsfiddle.net/ovqkcqvn/